# Which part of an SVG can be clicked on?

Tags: javascript, svg, click, addeventlistener

Would somebody please explain to me which part of an svg reposnds to a click? For example, is it the fill, or is it the stroke?

```
<svg class='arrow' id='play' version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M2.9,18.1c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.1-0.4-0.1V1c0-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.1l8.3,8.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.7L2.9,18.1z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M2.9,18.1c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.1-0.4-0.1V1c0-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.1l8.3,8.3c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.7L2.9,18.1z"/>
</g>
<line class="st0" x1="12.5" y1="0.5" x2="12.5" y2="18.5"/>
<g>
    <line class="st0" x1="15.5" y1="0.5" x2="15.5" y2="18.5"/>
</g>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

I have the following example [here](https://codepen.io/no3deluxe/pen/ZVbZxg?editors=0100) and the play/pause button (the middle of the three controls) seems to be unresponsive to clicks sometimes and seems as if the filled area does not respond.

I have tried using pointer-events and it does not seem to make any difference, even with the non-filled rectangle shape that has been added at the end of each svg element.

Would somebody be able to advise me on how svg elements respond to click events? And also, how would you get the whole of the square around the shape to respond to a click for a better user experience?

Comment: Try simply adding this to your event listener: `console.log(e.target);` Then click on your button a few times. You will see that the target will be the individual element being clicked within the SVG, meaning that unless you get a click on the wrapper (background), the `id` will be null, because it is not set for each _path_. You will need a different method of detecting a click on the p lay button vs using the id.

Comment: @MattClark what would you suggest to be the best way of achieving this? Is there a way to wrap the entire svg elements up and listen to that? Or would the svg fill up space within the div that is in turn not listened to? Or would looping over every element within the svg be a good move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default it's the fill. You can change this with the [pointer-events CSS property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).

e.target.id will give you the id of the element you clicked on, that's not going to be "play", it will be null as the path elements have no id and yet they are the things that can be clicked on.

Comment: I would add that if a shape doesn't have a fill but needs to be clickable you need to use a transparent fill like `fill:transparent` or `fill:rgba( whatever )` or `fill:hsla( whatever )`

Comment: @exaneta, absolutely not, use pointer-events instead. fill: transparent is far less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://codepen.io/no3deluxe/pen/ZVbZxg) scenario, I found the following to work

```
svg {
  pointer-events: stroke;
}
```

The svg element is now clickable all over. Previously it did not respond to the black fill.